# Issue sharing custom libraries with Module Federation plugin

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

Good afternoon,

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/blob/12.0.0/libs/mf/tutorial/tutorial.md) to share a library with Module Federation Plugin and Angular. Library is located in a different projects (not monorepo), and it is installed as npm dependency in two modules. I want to use this library to share data, so it contains a service with get/set methods to store values in a private variable.

Issue comes when I use the library in two modules. Looks like it is instantiated two times, because if I print the value in both modules, it has two different values at same time.

I´m using this config for the main module:

```
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  ['authentication-lib']);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "crmEcApp",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },
         remotes: {
             "userManagementApp": "userManagementApp@http://localhost:4501/remoteEntry.js",

         },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "authentication-lib": { singleton: true, eager:true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

And this config for the second module:

```
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  ['authentication-lib']);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "userManagementApp",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },

        // For remotes (please adjust)
         name: "userManagementApp",
         filename: "remoteEntry.js",
         exposes: {
           './UserManagementComponent': './/src/app/user-management/user-management.component.ts',
           './AuthModule': './/src/app/app.module.ts'
         },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "authentication-lib": { singleton: true, eager: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Library that I´m trying to share is authentication-lib.

Thanks.

**Update: added service**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthService {
  isAuthenticated: boolean = false;
```

Comment: I don’t think you should be using eager (not sure why but I received that feedback with a similar issue). I assume the shared service is providedIn root right? And it is not provided anywhere else? So try to remove eager and strictVersion from all configs (host and remotes) and see if that helps. Also, can you post that service?

Comment: I updated the case with the service. I faced a new "issue": if I access directly to "isAuthenticated" variable from both microfrontends, one of them has the correct value (true) and the other has the default value (false).

However, if I create get/set methods in the service to manipulate isAuthenticated variable, it seems variable is never updated and always has "false" value... :/

Comment: I removed eager and strictVersion, but nothing changed.

Comment: If your services use other services, they should also be marked as shared. Also, a quick fix could be, use providedIn: “platform”

Comment: @DanielMorcillo do you have any update on the fix ? I am still struggling to get the library in a different workspace sharing a common service between Microfront ends residing in different repo, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @VR1256 finally I did a different approach. I wanted to use Module Federation plugin because some modules were common for different webs that I was developing. As I had several problems with this, I created each module as a library, and my main webs are empy and they only load libraries that they need and do the routing.